# Site stuck in Maintenance mode in Drupal 7

Tags: php, database, drupal-7, maintenance-mode

My site is developed in Drupal 7. Recently I have put my site to maintenance mode. And now I need to put this site back to live.

Unfortunately I am not able to login as admin and 'Go Online'(Because of some modifications in the user login form). I have also tried to update the 'site_offline' variable by database query. But this also did not work. To my surprise, there was no variable like 'site_offline' in db. Why is this so?

Can anybody help to get this issue solved? Any help or suggestions will be a greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found a workaround for this problem. I logged in to the application by admin programmatically using below code,

```
global $user;
$user = user_load(1);
drupal_session_regenerate();
drupal_goto('user');
```

[Reference](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2570/how-to-log-in-programmatically-as-user-1-in-drupal-7)

After getting logged in, I changed the maintenance configuration from admin/config/development/maintenance.

### UPDATE

Please make sure to delete the above code once the site is set back from maintenance mode. Otherwise this will give administration access to any user visiting the website.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Just curious, did you manually delete all the contents for each cache table after updating the maintenance_mode variable?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue, and I add following statement to the end of the settings.php file. And it worked.

```
        $conf['maintenance_mode'] = 0;
```

Source : https://www.drupal.org/node/276457#comment-9364023

Comment: I've had this problem a few times, and this solution has always worked for me in the past. This time though, even with this any logged out session still loads in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do changes in database.

Just add **$conf['maintenance_mode'] = 0;** to your **settings.php** file.
 This will override the default settings.

Answer (score 3):

If you log yourself out and can't get back in, just add `/?q=user` after your website address and you'll be back to the user login page.

Comment: By far the easiest/safest method if you can see a login using this .. voted up.

Comment: This did not work for me (Drupal 7.69).  I had to use YOURSITE/user/login

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the crush shell for the site, you can simply run:

```
# from drupal root (/path/to/index.php)
drush vset maintenance_mode 0;
drush c all;
```

If not, or if that doesn't work, update the "maintenance_mode" property in the variable table to "i:0;" (not 0 because drupal stores and parses these settings as long blob).

```
#sql statement
UPDATE `variable` SET `value` = 'i:0;' WHERE `name` = 'maintenance_mode';
```

Note: if you only have access to the database, you will likely need to clear out all the cache tables manually.

Comment: I have tried the sql query to update the maintenance variable. But this did not work. Anyways thanks for your fast reply.

Answer (score 2):

I found that that the solution was to simply navigate to yoursitename/user/login

simply log in as the site admin and turn off maintenance mode.

Its a lot simpler than messing about with the code suggestions above...

The annoying thing is that this "simple" fix took me an hour of Googling and going down various rabbit holes suggested on other forums.

Perhaps we (as developers) should take some time to learn how to use the products we are asked to support?

Comment: This worked for me in 7.84 ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put it manually out of maintenance mode by editing index.php and setting the variable "maintenance_mode"

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
*
* The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
* prints the appropriate page.
*
* All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
* See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
*/


/**
* Root directory of Drupal installation.
*/
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());


require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
variable_set('maintenance_mode', 0);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2072055#comment-7784641

Comment: `Really` This what happen!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Drupal documentation:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/56995

It basically states what Alexander Farber posted, but indicates also that once you are logged on, you navigate to the Administration page, as per Drupal version, go to these links:

- Drupal 4: administer » settings (admin/settings)
- Drupal 5&6: Administer » Site configuration » Site maintenance (admin/settings/site-maintenance).
- Drupal 7: Administration » Configuration » Development » Maintenance Mode: remove the check mark on box "Put site into maintenance mode"

Comment: I think the "missing manual" bit of your answer is how you can navigate to a login screen. - the suggestion above of /?q=user did not work for me.

Also, the original questioner had modified their login in some way so they could not access the site as admin.  It does beg the question of how they were able to administer their site full stop, but I guess that's another question.

For anyone who is searching for how to find a login prompt because they wish to turn off admin mode.  simply navigate to:

YOURSITE/user/login

Answer (score 0):

It might sound crazy but in some Apache versions, default file for web server to open is **.html** and there is a **index.html** in Drupal 7 root directory and its content is :

```
Website is Under Construction ....
```

so just rename that file to something other than index, then your web server will opens index.php .